# Blackberry code signing 'unable to request signatures...'

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have taken a project created by someone else on another machine.

- I have filled in the [signed keys form](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys) and had my keys emailed to me.
- I have double clicked on each to install them: I then go to the signature tool in the vmTools folder. selected my .cod file (built today).
- I then get the list of cod files with 'not registered' next to them in the status column.
- I hit the request button and get the error. 'unable to request signatures until this application has been registered with all signing authorities. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the signing server may be down, you can check the current status of the signing server here:

[isthesigningserverdown.com](http://www.isthesigningserverdown.com)

It is always a quick and easy start to troubleshooting signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this blackberry.com reference](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Unable-to-request-signatures-until-this-application-has-been/ta-p/445846).

To prevent this being lost to link rot, I pasted the important content below.

**Note**: if you're using the Eclipse plugin, not the old JDE, then you would go to the **BlackBerry** menu, select **Sign**, and either **Install New Keys** or **Import Existing Keys**.  You must use *all three files* that BlackBerry (RIM) gave you.  For example, to install brand new keys:

> client-RBB-12341231.csi 
>   client-RCR-12341231.csi 
>   client-RRT-12341231.csi

or for an Import of existing keys:

> sigtool.csk 
>   sigtool.db

---

### Problem

In certain situations, when you attempt to sign your application using the SignatureTool application, you receive the following error:

> Unable to request signatures until this application has been registered with all signing authorities required.

### Cause

You are attempting to request code-signing signatures for your application but the SignatureTool is not registered with all the required signing authorities.

There are two types of RIM Code Signing framework signatures:

- **Required Signatures** - This is specified by the .csl file associated with the .cod file. A required signature is necessary to load your application on the device.
- **Optional Signatures** - This is specified by the .cso file associated with the .cod file. An optional signature indicates that the system may perform a runtime signature check on the application. If the application is not signed, it is not allowed to execute the intended method.

The SignatureTool prevents you from signing the application since it waits until all required signatures are in place. Required signatures are necessary for the application to load successfully on the device.

### Resolution

There are several different scenarios where the SignatureTool is not registered with the required code-signing servers.

- **Scenario 1 - Not Registered with Public Signing Authorities**

There are three public-signing authorities (RBB, RRT, and RCR) that represent different sections of the controlled application programming interface (API). When you receive code-signing keys, you receive three .csi files representing the three code-signing servers. It is important to register with all three servers. To determine which signature keys have been successfully installed and/or missing, please review this article

- **Scenario 2 - Attempting to use a Controlled Signing Authority**

There is an additional public-signing authority, the Certicom™ Crypto (RCC) signing authority, that controls access to Certicom cryptography functions on the device. Go to Certicom for more information on accessing the Certicom API’s on the device.

- **Scenario 3 - Attempting to use an Inaccessible Signing Authority**

Research In Motion® maintains its own internal signing authorities for the protection of API’s that are not exposed or data that is not public. It is not possible to gain access to these signing authorities and any reference to Research In Motion internal methods or data should be removed from your application to allow the SignatureTool to sign your application.

**Note**: JDE 4.1 allows you to turn on code-signing warnings under Preferences. This determines the areas of your application that are attempting to use signatures from each signing authority.

---

[Here's one more useful guide on the BlackBerry website](http://us.blackberry.com/content/dam/blackBerry/pdf/academic/BlackBerry%2B-%2BCode%2BSigning%2B-%2BStep%2BBy%2BStep%2BGuide-2.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally RIM's signing server fails.  I've seen it down for hours at a time.